# How to set ssh connection in Django?

Tags: python, django, ssh

I want to set and ssh connection using Django and access files on the host. I'm new to ssh and django. Can someone please explain how should I achieve this?

Comment: You could use the [`paramiko` library](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/).

Comment: You need to give more detail about what you want to do. What exactly are you doing with SSH?

Comment: So I want to login into ssh and then run some scripts in ssh and the output should be displayed on the Django template.

Comment: @Ashishnitinpatil Thanks that worked